# Non-interactive SQLite3 usage from bash script

Tags: bash, sqlite

I see plenty of examples showing how to use the sqlite3 interactive shell, e.g.:

```
$ sqlite3
$ sqlite3> SELECT * from x;
```

but I am looking for a way to create a table in a SQLite3 database with a bash script, aka, non-interactively.

For example, the following **doesn't** seem to work, it remains *interactive*:

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlite3 test.db  "create table n (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,f TEXT,l TEXT);"
sqlite3 test.db  "insert into n (f,l) values ('john','smith');"
sqlite3 test.db  "select * from n";
```

Comment: For example create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);

Comment: There is nothing to wake up, [SQLite3 does not use a server/daemon](https://sqlite.org/serverless.html).

Comment: thanks for that info. good to know. on a separate note, my answer actually doesn't work - it's still interactive.

Comment: Try moving your final semicolon inside the double quote, instead of outside.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like it's as simple as

```
#!/bin/bash
sqlite3 test.db  "create table n (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,f TEXT,l TEXT);"
sqlite3 test.db  "insert into n (f,l) values ('john','smith');"
sqlite3 test.db  "select * from n;"
```

from https://mailliststock.wordpress.com/2007/03/01/sqlite-examples-with-bash-perl-and-python/

Comment: ok, I confirmed that this works - this is non-interactive, as long as test.db exists

Comment: In the last command, you might have intended the semi-colon needs to be inside the quotes, otherwise it's a command to Bash (which, in this case, does nothing).

Comment: thanks Paddy, I fixed that semicolon placement

Answer (score 29):

While the above should work, I think it is better not to have to invoke sqlite3 multiple times, therefore I think the following is preferable:

```
#!/bin/sh
sqlite3 test.db <<EOF
create table n (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,f TEXT,l TEXT);
insert into n (f,l) values ('john','smith');
select * from n;
EOF
```

Note that unless you *really* need to use bash, you should prefer "/bin/sh" as your shebang, for portability reasons.

Comment: I do not think you should ever prefer /bin/sh as shebang: usually sh is symlinked to bash so that any code that is valid in bash but not in sh will not be noticed until finally someone runs your code on some eon-old platform (Solaris 9, for example) which does really have a difference between sh and bash and it will throw errors.

Comment: @Cheiron: Your point about unnoticed bashisms in a script with a /bin/sh shebang is well-taken, but I still disagree.  I don't know offhand how common it is in the Linux word to symlink /bin/sh to /bin/bash, but it isn't universal, e.g, in Lubuntu (the only Linux system handy to me at the moment), /bin/sh is symlinked to /bin/dash, not /bin/bash.  More importantly, all the world in not Linux.  Apart from "eon-old" platforms, modern, very much in use systems, like the one I use all the time, FreeBSD, simply do not have /bin/bash.  I stand by my recommendation.

Comment: is the FreeBSD argument not an argument for /bin/bash? Dash is not sh, bash is not sh and zsh is not sh, so I think one should pick the shebang one is actually working with. If I create a bash script and put /bin/sh above it, I can not actually test wether or not it runs on sh since /bin/sh is symlinked to /bin/bash on my system, so I should put /bin/bash as shebang, right?

Comment: @Cheiron: Only if you don't care about portability.  What any professional *should* do is to know the limits of /bin/sh and write scripts for that. Yes, this requires that the script-writer actually *know* what is supported, and not supported, by the standard shell. That's part of learning your craft properly. (In a professional environment, scripts should get reviewed by other team members.) One thing I learned in the course of my 30+-year career in software development is *always* prioritize portability. A portable shell script will run fine even if sh happens to be bash, but not vice versa.

Comment: @Cheiron:  Note that I think that bash and zsh are poor choices for a *system* shell because of their non-standard extensions, whereas dash is much better choice  because it sticks to the standard pretty closely as I understand.

Comment: I dont have 30 years of experience, but I don't dare assume that my bash just runs on sh without being able to check. I also do not think that learning your craft is somehow equal to making no mistakes, especially not when tired. I do like portability, but I need at least one test system for every supported platform or I cannot confirm wether or not the code is actually supported everywhere. So as long as I dont have sh, i prefer using /bin/bash as to not give false promises: I can only test for bash so I put /bin/bash.

Comment: @Cheiron, you say: "sh is symlinked to bash so that any code that is valid in bash but not in sh will not be noticed" but the bash manpage says "If bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well". The whole point of the symlink is so that invalid sh code in a bash script WILL be noticed. The fact that you have a preference for /bin/bash is fine, but to then conclude that varro's point is invalid doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MikeS So why can I write `/bin/sh` as shebang and then use [[? [[ does not exist in sh. So effectively I am lying when sh is the shebang, since it will only run if you symlinked the sh to a bash-like shell. That is my point here: sh is obsolete and confusing at this point so stick to the shell you know it will work on.

Comment: @Cheiron because... ehm... well, I guess "conforming to the POSIX standard" means that "Yeah, I'm POSIX conformant, but I'm going to leave the bashisms in place too. So don't think that I'm a strictly conformant shell, and if you hope that by using /bin/sh will mean that your code is portable, you will be sorely disappointed." :-\  I'm going to sheepishly go program in Python for a while. You're right. When you can't depend on the standards- don't expect the standards to be standard.

Comment: "If you don't care about portability" should rather be rephrased as "if you don't plan on TESTING for portability", which is nearly always the case if you're writing homegrown stuff. And even when deciding to only support bash, don't be surprised about the number of portability issues you will still have across different bash major *and* minor versions and different OS'es (or rather, bin utils, such as sed, awk, etc). Much rather add a version check that says "hey I only tested this on bash 4.3.2~special-build.a.b.c on os such and such" than SUGGESTING portability that really isn't there.

Answer (score 12):

You can disable interactive mode using the -batch option:

```
sqlite3 -batch test.db "create table n (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,f TEXT,l TEXT);"
```

Comment: Does not work using cmd internal commands, like as `sqlite3 -separator ',' -cmd ".import file.csv' tmp" -batch tmp.db`.

Comment: @e-info128 not sure if you got the answer to this already but `cat << EOF | sqlite3 tmp.db <newline> .import file.csv tmp EOF` works for me.

Answer (score 3):

This works too

```bash
sqlite3 "${DB_FILE_NAME}" < data_model.sql
sqlite3 "${DB_FILE_NAME}" < dml.sql
```